# For REINFORCE, why do different books give different algorithms?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

The discount rate appears twice in the REINFORCE algorithm in Sutton and Barto (2018).  However, in three major books (Graesser and Keng (2020); Morales (2020); Ravichandiran (2020)) on reinforcement learning and in numerous papers and videos, the discount rate only appears once.  Why is this?

Comment: It is a somewhat contentious issue in practical RL. Theoretically the second discount should appear, but in practice a lot of people don’t do this. There’s a paper that shows without the second discounting then the ‘gradient’ that people use is not actually a gradient. https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07073